# What does "packages have unmet dependecies" mean and what can I do about it?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, dependencies

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 account-plugin-facebook : Depends: libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth but it is not going to be installed or
                                    ubuntu-system-settings-online-accounts but it is not going to be installed
 gvfs-daemons : Depends: x11-utils
 indicator-bluetooth : Depends: unity-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                                ubuntu-system-settings but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5feedback5 : Depends: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 yelp : Depends: libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libyelp0 (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Internal error, Upgrade broke stuff
```

How do I remove this error?

I'm new to Ubuntu so please give the details in the answer.

What kind of error is this and why does it occur?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? What did you do to get this? In a nutshell "packages have unmet dependencies" means that a package requires another package that's not available or not to be installed.

Comment: Which error occurs when you execute the following command? `sudo apt-get install libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth`

Answer (score 1):

That error means the package you are trying to install depends on some other packages, but for whatever reason, they aren't going to be installed. There are a few ways to try to get around this.

1. Installing each listed dependency manually. You can try running `apt-get install` on all the dependencies listed in that window, but this could take forever and lead to more dependencies that need to be installed.
2. Using the Ubuntu Software Center. This might be easier, since it's more user-friendly and automated. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and try installing you package from there.
3. Using `aptitude`. There is an alternative to `apt-get`, called `aptitude`, that will try harder than `apt-get` to fulfill your request. While it may work well, it could also end up removing important packages that conflict with what you're trying to install. Use this tool with care.

I would try running `sudo apt-get install x11-utils` before trying to install your package to see if that fixes anything. Also try running `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure everything is updated and installed.